# Como aparecer required num input sem form?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria fazer um formulário mas sem usar `<form>` porque pretendo mandar os `inputs`por `ajax`. O problema é que se tirar o form, ele não irá ser required pois tal como tem dito no W3Schools

> O atributo **required** especifica que um `input` tem de ser
>   preenchido **antes** de ser submetido

Sendo assim, o que posso fazer para conseguir? Procurei e encontrei este código:

```
document.getElementById('put_id_here').validity.valid;
```

Mas o código acima não deu resultado.

Comment: Isso funciona bem https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/97k5n5yj/ qual é o problema que estás a ter?

Comment: Tente adicionar um botão `<button>`. Eu tentei e não deu resposta

Comment: Eu tinha o id mal definido no que tentei mas eu queria que ele desse trigger ao required, e não dizer se está vazio ou não

Comment: @I_like_trains ok, se queres usar o UI nativo isso não dá sem `form.submit`. Podes fazer um teu, usando o `.validity.valid`. Mas se queres que seja automático via browser usa `<form>` e depois impede de ser submetido com `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Sergio Pensando melhor, acho que vou apenas mudar a cor da borda para vermelho com um aviso ao lado, mais simples e mais agradável. Poste a sua resposta que eu darei como aceite.

Comment: @I_like_trains feito. Juntei mais uma ideia que pode ser útil: `:empty` do CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o seletor `:invalid` para aplicar CSS ao input não validado. A única desvantagem é que o CSS carrega logo desde o inicio. Por isso podes juntar uma classe para juntar ao elemento quando receber foco pela primeira vez.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('put_id_here');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var info = document.querySelector('p');

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.classList.add('validate');
});

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (input.validity.valid) {
    info.textContent = 'Tudo OK!';
  } else {
    info.textContent = 'O input tem de ser preenchido!';
  }
});
```

```css
.validate:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="put_id_here" required>
<button>Enviar</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: O Senhor poderia me explicar esse tal de `validity.valid` dentro do código? O nome é bem sugestivo mas não consigo palavras para explicar hehehe

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo seria mais ou menos: `input.validador.valido`, ou seja o `input.validity` é um object [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)  que contém uma série de valores relacionados com o estado de validação do input.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar assim.

```
<form action="javascript:enviar();"> 
   <input type="text" name="text" required>
</form>

<script>

    function enviar() {
        var text = document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value;
        alert( text );
    }

</script>
```